# Linux os suddently stopped booting

Tags: boot, hard-disk, hardware, system-failure

I use my linux computer every day for all kind of task, however, after an inespected power failure when I was using it, the os simply stopped booting. It happens every time I try to start the system, instead of normally booting an error menssage is printed and then nothing more happens.

The linux system I'm using is POP-OS 22.04 which is installed on a nvme drive.

The printed menssage is:

```
[4.891938] Dev loop0: unable to read RDB block 8
[5.179002] 
[5.981357] Dev loop15: unable to read RDB block 8
```

I'm not sure if the problem is relationed with hardware failure, consindering that the same thing happened one week before, but different of what I'm experiencing now the os booted normally after I reboot my pc.

Thus, I'd like to know if there is any way to solve the problem and make Pop-os boot again or ,if not possible, recover my data from the problematic drive copying to an other.

Comment: I have edited my post, I hope my question is clearer now.

Comment: Please remove `quiet` as your boot option, try to boot and then upload a photo of your screen. These two lines are not really informative at least for me.